# Can't install libdouble-conversion1 on Ubuntu-19.10

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, cisco, packet-analyzer

When I tried to install Cisco packet tracer from `deb` file it gave the following error:

```
Unpacking packettracer (7.3.0) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packettracer:
 packettracer depends on libdouble-conversion1; however:
  Package libdouble-conversion1 is not installed.
 packettracer depends on qt-at-spi; however:
  Package qt-at-spi is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package packettracer (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.63ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.10-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 packettracer
```

Then I tried installing `libdouble-conversion1` using command `sudo apt-get install libdouble-conversion1` . It gives the following error

```
Package libdouble-conversion1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libdouble-conversion1' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: You haven't told us your release, it's available for some releases but not others - https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libdouble-conversion1

Comment: I've edited the question. I'm using 19.10. I see it is not available here. How to resolve this issue ? @guiverc

Comment: libdouble-conversion1 : Probably use an 18.04 or 19.04 package →   https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&keywords=libdouble-conversion1&searchon=names ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Download these packages first:

   1. libdouble-conversion1 (http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/double-conversion/libdouble-conversion1_3.1.0-3_amd64.deb)
   2. qt-at-spi (http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/q/qt-at-spi/qt-at-spi_0.4.0-9_amd64.deb)
   3. libjpeg-turbo8 (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo8_2.0.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
   4. libjpeg8 (http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libj/libjpeg8-empty/libjpeg8_8c-2ubuntu8_amd64.deb)
   5. packet tracer 7.3
2. Open terminal and change directory to Downloads (where the downloaded packages exist)
3. Make all the downloaded packages executable (`chmod +x packagename`)
4. Copy `/home/username/.config/mimeapps.list` to `/root/.config/`
5. Install libdouble-conversion1 and qt-at-spi packages (`sudo dpkg -i packagename`)
6. Install libjpeg-turbo8 package. Here, you may find library conflict error. If so, remove the old one (`sudo apt purge packagename`). There will be some warning.Just type this command (`sudo apt --fix-broken install`). And then, remove again. Now, you can install libjpeg-turbo8 package again.
7. Install libjpeg8 package.
8. Finally, you can install Packet Tracer 7.3 package.\

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use packages from other versions:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/d/double-conversion/libdouble-conversion1_2.0.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./libdouble-conversion1_2.0.1-4ubuntu1_amd64.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qt-at-spi/qt-at-spi_0.4.0-3_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./qt-at-spi_0.4.0-3_amd64.deb
```

And then, install Packet Tracer from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install <absolute/path/to/your/package>
```

Comment: Have you tried it by yourself installing packet tracer this way? Packets from other versions could depend on other packages of different versions, although you have the same packages with proper to your distributive version already installed. In this case, by installing packages with not proper versions, you could break your system, by getting dependency problems.

Answer (score 1):

After downloading packet tracer,I tried installing it with `sudo dpkg -i PacketTracer_730_amd64.deb` and got this:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of packettracer:
 packettracer depends on qt-at-spi; however:
  Package qt-at-spi is not installed.
```

When i tried  to install `qt-at-spi` I got this message

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 qt-at-spi : Depends: libqt4-dbus (>= 4:4.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8~) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Running `sudo apt --fix-broken install` fixed all my issues,packet tracer was installed.