# Can't install Packet Tracer 3.0 in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04

When installing new Packet Tracer 3.0, in Ubuntu 20.04, it requires a qt-at-spi file, now this has other dependency files, that do not support installation in ubuntu 20.04, therefore can't be installed directly, and also to install per file bases will take me eternity. Is there any repository where the file qt-at-spi, comes with all it's the dependency?

Comment: Try with this solution, click on link https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206794/cant-install-libdouble-conversion1-on-ubuntu-19-10

Comment: Thank you @RenatoCruzaleguiCruzalegui, I figured it out. I appreciated very much for your help.